# get materialized view state, unknown state

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

good morning friends,

How can I know if a materialized view was updated correctly.

The refresh methods that I am using in the views are: complete, fast and forced.

I am currently using the state of the view to identify if it updated correctly, but it is causing me problems.

code:

```
 SELECT OWNER,MVIEW_NAME,AFTER_FAST_REFRESH, STALENESS, COMPILE_STATE FROM DBA_MVIEWS
```

It appears to me that it needs to compile or unknown status (column: COMPILE_STATE), I was investigating and there are several reasons why it may appear as unknown, what other alternative do I have to obtain the update status of the view or what could I do?

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you,
Greetings.

Comment: "but it is causing me problems" - what problems? STALENESS should be "FRESH" and COMPILE_STATE="VALID"

Comment: these are the states currently. 1) STALENESS =NEEDS_COMPLILE, COMPILE_STATE=NEEDS_COMPLILE 2) STALENESS =UNDEFINED, COMPILE_STATE=VALID

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `DBA_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES.html

> DBA_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES describes refresh times of all materialized views in the database.

and [DBA_REGISTERED_MVIEWS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_REGISTERED_MVIEWS.html)

> DBA_REGISTERED_MVIEWS describes all registered materialized views (registered at a master site or a master materialized view site) in the database. Its columns are the same as those in ALL_REGISTERED_MVIEWS.